# Changing map marker colors

Tags: google-maps-api-3

With the depreciation of dynamic icons (https://developers.google.com/ 
chart/infographics/docs/dynamic_icons), I now have an additional task 
added to my endless list -- that is -- find a way to change marker 
colors, add numbers to icons, etc.

So, before I head off and start creating static icons for every 
combination possible in our map application; I am going to ask the 
team if there is any other way...

Team -- is there any other way??

... as the maps API does not provide anything as useful as dynamic 
icons.

Depreciating the dynamic icons service really hurt (and some may even 
consider it evil) !

Answer (score 0):

The most complete collection I know is here:

http://mapicons.nicolasmollet.com/

http://mapicons.nicolasmollet.com/numbers-letters/

There is the option for custom colors at the end of the markers, but it's not as convenient as Google Charts dynamic icons. The nicolasmollet page say that you have to download and host icons in your server.